# Mongoose schema: validate before set

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to validate a field before setting it, but my current code runs the validator *after* setting it. Is there a way to do it the other way around?

```
  password: { 
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validate: {
      validator: function(password) {
        return password.length > 9;
      }
    },
    set: v => encryptPassword(v)
```

This code checks the encrypted password's length but I want to check the unencrypted password's length.

Answer (score 1):

Use **pre middleware**:

```js
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.password = /*encrypted password algorithm*/;
  next();
});
```

The validator will run before the pre middleware, so you encrypt the password after having validated the password. We use a regular `function` because we need access to `this`, and I'm not sure what kind of password encryption you're using.

Comment: I don't think I'm meant to use that since the password is supposed to be encrypted before it's saved in the database.

Comment: The pre middleware will run **before** the document is saved to database.

Comment: I tried your code but it failed the pre-written tests I was provided. I ended up implementing the validation in the encryption function `encryptPassword`

Comment: What was the output and what was your expected output?

Comment: My output was the non-encrypted password, expected output is the encrypted password.

Comment: You sure you are using the algorithm and not typing the comment I put

Comment: And it's on the schema not the model

Comment: const userSchema = new Schema({
...
});

userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.password = encryptPassword(this.password);
  next();
});

Comment: Hmm that's weird, worked for me. May I see what is in your encryptPassword function?

Comment: let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10); 
    let hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt); 
    return hash;